# Finding Duplicate Values in a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm writing a script to find duplicated values in a dictionary. My dictionary `duties` has an integer key and a list as a value. My task is to make a new dictionary `duties_without_duplicates` without duplicate values.

```
duties = { 
    0: ["Submit an assignment","Submit an assignment"],
    1: ["Submit an assignment", "Finish a book review"]
}

duties_without_duplicates = {
    0: ["Submit an assignment"],
    1: ["Submit an assignment", "Finish a book review"]
}
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is the order of the items in the lists important?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove duplicates from a list, while preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-while-preserving-order)

Answer (score 1):

If the order of items in your lists is not important, you can simply pass the lists to a `set` constructor -

```py
duties = { 
    0: ["Submit an assignment","Submit an assignment"],
    1: ["Submit an assignment", "Finish a book review"]
}
duties_without_duplicates = {k: list(set(v)) for k, v in duties.items()}
```

**Output**

```
{0: ['Submit an assignment'],
 1: ['Submit an assignment', 'Finish a book review']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grouby` from `itertools`, and use the keys provided by groupby iterator for the unique values in the list, and you can implement a dictionary comprehension to achieve that:

```py
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> {key:[k for k,v in groupby(values)] for key,values in duties.items()}

{0: ['Submit an assignment'], 1: ['Submit an assignment', 'Finish a book review']}
```

As I've mentioned in comments as well, above solution will work only if the values list is sorted, otherwise, you can use following method:

```py
result = {}
for key,values in duties.items():
    temp = []
    for v in values:
        if v not in temp:
            temp.append(v)
    result[key]=temp

# result: 
{0: ['Submit an assignment'], 1: ['Submit an assignment', 'Finish a book review']}
```

Comment: Depending on the lists - `itertools.groupby` might not remove all duplicates.

Comment: @Mortz, you are right, it'll work only if the list is sorted else it will not work. But since the data mentioned by OP is sorted, so I didn't think in that direction.

Comment: Yes - just wanted to call it out as the results of `groupby` on an unsorted list might be surprising

Comment: @Mortz, thanks for the comment, I've added alternate solution as well.